# Is there a way to dynamically create a contract that points to a previous contract?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, contract-design, remix

I would like to implement a tracking system .. where i track events between two parties who deliver an item between them .. then the receiver would deliver it to another person and so on...

I would like to create a contract for each transaction (between every two) at the same time , I would like to still be able to track all the chain .. the originator and the previous contract ...

Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

**Preface**: If you want to use web3 to create that interaction, the following should work:

If you use the `.deploy()` method on a constructed contract through web3, it should return the address upon `receipt` and the instance itself upon `confirmation`.

```
myContract.deploy({
  data: '0x12345...',
  arguments: [123, 'My String']
})
.send({
  from: '0x1234567890123456789012345678901234567891', // owner address
  gas: 1500000,
  gasPrice: '30000000000000'
}, function(error, transactionHash){ ... })
.on('error', function(error){ ... })
.on('transactionHash', function(transactionHash){ ... })
.on('receipt', function(receipt){
  console.log(receipt.contractAddress) // contains the new contract address
})
.on('confirmation', function(confirmationNumber, receipt){ ... })
.then(function(newContractInstance){
  console.log(newContractInstance.options.address) // instance with the new contract address
})
```

Source: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#deploy

Answer (score 0):

Let's clarify a few conceptual things.

> I would like to create a contract for each transaction

Not very likely. Transactions are not contracts. Some transactions deploy contracts because that is their purpose, and other transactions interact with contracts. The closest association I can think of that would possibly be sensible is a contract that records transaction documents of a certain type. That could be one contract that handles all instances of a class.

> track events between two parties who deliver an item between them

Here, the language is a little challenging to unpack because "events" has a very specific meaning in Ethereum, as do "transaction" and "contract." I will interpret it like this to reduce confusion:

> "track interactions between two parties that participate in the delivery of a product."

Let us unpack that.

**Product:** Some sort of physical object with a representation in a contract. This is likely best held in a single contract that stores product info and possibly other info. This is probably best treated as rows in (logical) table, or instances of a class, in you prefer. Start here: https://medium.com/robhitchens/solidity-crud-part-1-824ffa69509a or here: [Are there well-solved and simple storage patterns for Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/are-there-well-solved-and-simple-storage-patterns-for-solidity)

**parties that participate in the delivery:** This implies there is a business process with steps that flow in a certain way. Absent a better description of the use-case, let's say the two parties have to sign off, and then ownership is transferred, a.k.a. delivery.

This *process* (whatever it is) is precisely what a contract is for. A contract can hold the product info, including ownership, and enforce a process that strictly restricts how ownership will be transferred.

Contracts can talk to other contracts. So, the transfer process enforced by the products contract can be constrained by a sign off by, say, a delivery service. Consider two "approvers" who get the ball rolling, some custody data to indicate the delivery company that is authoritative for the next step, and a delivery confirmation that concludes the transfer of ownership.

In such a scenario, there is a single products contract that one can consult to discover the status/ownership of *any* product instance and the history of things that have happened to it.

Hope it helps.